# option to add gpu on gcloud not available?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I never had this issue until recently, but now, when creating a VM, the option to add a gpu is always not clickable.

[image]

this is what it looks like.what is the cause for this?

this is not caused because there are no gpus in my region, I checked a lot of them. also I don't think its an issue with my account, I CAN make gpu instanced through the marketplace

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because of the current machine type that has been set. You can only attach GPUs to general-purpose N1 machine types. GPUs are not supported for other machine types. Feel free to check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#gpus) for reference.